# What do you call someone who finds everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, nicknames

I'm trying to define a character for a short story I'm writing, but I'm having a hard time defining him.

He has the ability to find everything.

What you do call someone who can find anything/everything?

Comment: Not an answer, but made me think of this! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seeker_(The_Who_song)

Comment: ..............my wife...................

Comment: That's funny. It made me think of this, though I'm not sure I'd propose "finder" as an answer, either. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Finder_(U.S._TV_series)

Comment: a search engine ?

Comment: What do you mean by "find everything"? He's good and finding information? He knows how to find his way around a geography/location? He can find lost keys? All of the above?

Comment: Have you ever read the Sword of Truth series by Terry Goodkind?  The protagonist is proclaimed a "Seeker of Truth" and must find answers to anything he does not understand.  I know it is not exactly what you are looking for, but 'petitor veritatis' means virtually the same thing, and, hopefully, would not make people think you were just stealing from Goodkind.  You could turn it into some kind of "Seeker of Truth" in regards to the objects he hunts.

Comment: A human search engine? If someone needs something, he can find it for them, no matter if it's information, a physical object etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's this film, a classic, starring Steve McQueen and Richard Attenborough, set during the second World War at an Air Force Prisoner of War camp in Germany. The film, if you haven't guessed by now, is called *The Great Escape*, based on real-life events that happened in [Stalag Luft III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalag_Luft_III), Sagan, once a German town, 100 miles south-east of Berlin.

In the film there is a Flight Lieutenant pilot called Robert Hendley, an American in the RAF, whose nickname is "**the scrounger**"

> **who finds what the others need, from a camera to clothes and identity
>   cards**

Interestingly, the actor who portrayed this role, the gorgeous-looking James Garner, had been a soldier in the Korean war and he too had been a scrounger during that time. Unfortunately, today the term has very negative connotations especially in BrEng where it is synonymous with *moocher*, *sponger* and  a *freeloader* but according to *[War Slang](http://archive.org/stream/War_Slang/War_Slang_djvu.txt). American Fighting Words and Phrases Since the Civil War* by Paul Dickson, its meaning was *slightly* more noble.

> Scrounge. To appropriate; to misappropriate. *In Behind the Barrage*,
>   published  shortly after the war, British writer G. Goodchild
>   discusses the term:
>
> In the category of "odd jobs" came  "scrounging." "Scrounging" is
>   eloquent armyese; it covers pilfering, commandeering,  "pinching,"
>   and many other familiar terms.  You may scrounge for rations, kit,
>   pay, or  leave. Signalers are experts at it, and they  usually
>   scrounge for wire. Scrounging for  wire is legitimized by the War
>   Office, and  called by the gentler name of "*[salving](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/salve?q=salving#salve-2)*."

and further on

> scrounger. One adept at acquiring food  and other goods.

Oxford Dictionaries says *[scrounger](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/scrounger)* in AmEng is

> A cleverly resourceful person who finds and procures items for a
>   specific purpose

So, it kinda fits if the character is American or is given the nickname of Hendly; however, the author would have to give a brief justification for this name.

Comment: Sounds good to me, though a scrounger to me was someone who begged for food

Comment: @AndrewLazarus  I had completely forgotten about this question until a few days ago when it was upvoted, and now it's been accepted! Glad to have been of some assistance.

Comment: +1 for *the scrounger*, and though I am unable to corroborate this, **PP** claims that his father, *Col. Edmond Petit* (pilot, aviation historian, poet, and tunnel digger) was one of the captured officers that built a tunnel and effected the largest escape of WWII from a Nazi POW camp, providing some of the inspiration for the Hollywood film *The Great Escape*, see [**Chicago Humanities Festival interview w/PP**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWZfPtL1V9c).

Comment: @LittleEva Another clip of PP, thank you. He seems to be a bit of a hero for you,  doesn't he? Have you tried  writing to him? A fan letter, why not? :)

Comment: He's definitely amazing Mari-Lou, but perhaps I'm giving you the wrong impression. I'm not *obsessed or anything, it's just that we have been discussing PP & MoW and I've done a bit of W3 research, thought the *coincidence* with your answer here and what I discovered was rather remarkable.

Comment: W3? Is that a typo for WW2? I'm not saying you have to be obsessed to be a fan, just an admirer. James Garner, now how gorgeous was he? Yum, yum :) They don't make 'em like they used to.

Comment: Mari-Lou, merely orthographic play, W3 = WWW. They don't? Huh, I thought they made 'em the *exact* same *beast-with-two-backs* way. Garner don't look so good today, I prefer George Clooney. :-) Sent mail.

Answer (score 1):

[Trouvaille](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=trouver&searchmode=none): it means a lucky find or discovery

Comment: What if it's not a lucky find, but he knows he will find it, and he'll go to great lengths to get hold of anything

Comment: Hmm, a curse then?  Infaust http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Infaust

Answer (score 1):

If they're the first to find things:

> [pathfinder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathfinder) - a person or group that is the first to do something
>   and that makes it possible for others to do the same thing

If their ability to find things is divine or they have foresight, they might be a:

> [diviner](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/diviner) - someone who claims to discover hidden knowledge with
>   the aid of supernatural powers
>
> or a
>
> [seer](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/seer) - a person with unusual powers of foresight

If they are always in search of finding things, they may be a:

> [fortune-hunter](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fortune-hunter) - a person who seeks to secure a fortune

If they just have good luck, they may have a lot of:

> [serendipity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serendipity) - luck that takes the form of finding valuable or
>   pleasant things that are not looked for